# Fade effect on Scroll - What does the given code mean?

Tags: javascript

I was creating a tribute page and i wanted to create a fade effect on scroll. I searched the web and found this piece of code.This works as a treat but i want to know what this really means.

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var windowBottom = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight();
      $(".fade").each(function() {
        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        
        /* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
        if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
          if ($(this).css("opacity")==0) {$(this).fadeTo(2500,1);}
        } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
          if ($(this).css("opacity")==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
        }
      });
    }).scroll(); //invoke scroll-handler on page-load
  });
```

Comment: It's already explained in comment part. I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to explain the part of code that is missing comment. Each line is explained now.

```js
// When window loads
$(window).on("load",function() {
    // attach scroll event to invoke
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      // get the bottom value using the total height and window scrollTop position
      // usually on first load it will be 0 + total height which is bottom.
      var windowBottom = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight();
      // on each element that has fade class
      $(".fade").each(function() {
        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        
        /* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
        if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
          // if opacity is already 0, make it 1 slowly [2500]
          if ($(this).css("opacity")==0) {$(this).fadeTo(2500,1);}
          
        } else { 
          //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
          if ($(this).css("opacity")==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
        }
      });
    }).scroll(); //invoke scroll-handler on page-load
});
```